# Symfony uploads file with read permission

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I am using [laravel valet for windows](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/valet-windows) and php version is 7.2.12. My problem is when i try to upload file, there is not any error. it uploads to correct folder with correct name and extension. But when i try to open file i am getting error:

[image: error description]

here is my script:

```
$filename = $uniqid . '.' . $attachment->guessExtension();
try {
    $attachment->move(
        $this->getParameter('attachments_directory'),
        $filename
    );
} catch (FileException $e) {
    $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
}
```

searched for reason but nothing found. I think may be problem is in `php.ini`

Comment: Have you checked your umask?

Comment: yes it is 0 @vytsci

Comment: I had this strange behavior once. When chmod was set as a string rather than numeric value. For example somewhere in code you have chmod setting that sets chmod to '0777' rather than 0777 as for example. And that somehow makes chmod confused.